# Increment number in a cell - JavaScript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript with jQuery. I have the following

```
var $ticket = $nxt.parent().prev().children('.ticket');
```

and `$ticket.text()` is integer 1.

I want to increment it by 1 when when I click as;

```
$('.next').click(function()
```

How can I do this??

Comment: Have you read the `.html()` documentation? http://api.jquery.com/html/ (although `.text()` would be better here imo).

Comment: I changed it.. now hav a look at..

Comment: Still,  read the documentation about http://api.jquery.com/text/ and you will know how to set the value.

Comment: is there any chance for something like `$ticket.data("currentIndex", 1);`
        `$ticket.data("currentIndex", $ticket.data("currentIndex") + 1);`

Comment: Yes that works (try it). But it will not updated the value displayed in the cell.

Comment: you had left out the increment, make sure my edit says what you wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fancy solution would be

```
$.fn.extend({
  increment: function () {
    return this.text( function (i, currentText) {
      return parseInt(currentText, 10) + 1;
    });
  }
});
```

In your case use as:

```
$nxt.parent().prev().children('.ticket').increment();
```

Also see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/WDkm2/1/).

Comment: nb: jQuery plugins are supposed to work on multiple elements - this one won't.

Comment: @Tomalak ah yes, sneaky - using the function-based `.text()` call.  I was looking for the `.each()` that is normally needed to iterate over a jQuery object.  Nice :)

Comment: @Tomalak your inner callback is more complicated than it needs to be - .text(f) callback is supplied and returns the new text - should just be `return parseInt(t, 10) + 1` - see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/kcpLV/

Comment: @Alnitak: Thanks. :) Fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat inspired by the original version of Tomalak's answer, you can use the callback-based version of `.text` to change the value in a single jQuery call:

```
$ticket.text(function(i, t) {
    return parseInt(t, 10) + 1;
});
```

For those of you that tried to use `++`, it won't work for two reasons:

1. You can only use `++` on variables, not the return value of a function
2. Even then, in postfix mode it would have returned the *old* value, not the incremented value

Answer (score 0):

```
$ticket.click(function(e) { 
    $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) + 1); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Same here, `.val()` only works on form field and `$ticket` does not appear to be a form field.

Comment: What happens if the value of `this` is `08`? :P

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $ticket.val($ticket.val()+1)
```

**EDIT**

```
$ticket.text(parseInt($ticket.text(),10)+1);
```

If the element is somwhere other than a form

Sorry for the mistake, `++` doesnt work here. Have edited the solution accordingly.

Comment: Only works for form fields. As far as I can tell, `$ticket` is not a form field.

Comment: `$ticket.text($ticket.text()+1);` is adding 1 at the end of value.. why is this happening and how to fix??

Comment: actually check it, it is ' parseInt($ticket.text())+1 ' you left out the parseInt part

Comment: I get the error `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation` for using `++` this way. You can only use it on variables.

Comment: @Felix yes, because you can't `++` something that isn't a variable. Hence the note in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, ++ doesnt work here. Have edited the solution accordingly.

Comment: Isnt the radix parameter optional?? By default it converts to a base of 10 right.

Comment: @Balanivash no - if undefined a number starting 0 _may_ be parsed as octal and one starting 0x as hex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt